# Which scripture recommends Sharma Title for Brahmins?

Tags: title

I think Sharma title is recommended to be used by brahmins.

Which scripture recommends to use Sharma Title for Brahmins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pāraskara-gṛhyasūtrā, I.17.4 :**

> *4. **(The name) of a Brâhmana (should end in) sarman**, that of a Kshatriya in varman, that of a Vaisya in gupta.*

**manu smriti 2.32 :**

> ***śarmavad brāhmaṇasya** syād rājño rakṣāsamanvitam | vaiśyasya puṣṭisaṃyuktaṃ śūdrasya preṣyasaṃyutam || 32 ||*
>
> ***The name of the Brāhmaṇa should be expressive of ‘peace,’** that of the Kṣatriya, of ‘protection’; that ot the Vaiśya, of ‘prosperity,’
> and that of the Śūdra, of ‘submissiveness.’*

Comment: This is different from what the OP is asking. In the śloka from Pāraskaragṛhyasūtra you quoted, Śarman, Varman, etc. is not a title, but the suffix (ending part) of the name of the person. For e.g. Viṣṇuśarman, Candravarman, Jayavarmana, Candragupta, etc. In Candravarman, 'varman' is part of the same word, not a different word. Names with titles are like Vācaspati Miśra, Kumārila Bhaṭṭa, Kāśīnātha Upādhyāya, etc. Here 'Miśra', 'Bhaṭṭa', 'Upādhyāya', etc. is not part of the name, but are titles.

Comment: Yes it is a suffix but that's what i guess OP is looking for in this case but OP can confirm

Comment: Perhaps, because I am not familiar with Śarmā being used as a title in Sanskrit śāstras, unlike say 'Bhaṭṭa'. The use of Śarmā like it's now, seems something which might have started in colonial period.

Comment: Yes not used as part of name while addressing other person in shastras. In abhivadaye it is added as a suffix with name by all brahmans